# Search for Multiple Polygons in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, polygon

Is there a way to do a search for features that occupy more than one polygon in ArcMap?

I am working with a Parcel layer, and there are some cases where the parcels will take up multiple polygons (for example if they are bisected by a centerline).

Comment: The answer depends on your data structures.  For example, one parcel might be represented by multiple records in a polygon layer, so your problem is one of finding duplicate parcel identifiers in its attribute table.  Even when each parcel is represented by a unique record, that record's polygon might have multiple connected components, so your problem is to identify such records.  Perhaps both situations pertain.  Perhaps you're in a different situation altogether.  It would help if you could clarify this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a [Spatial Join](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s0000002n000000.htm) of your parcels to the polygon layer.  The output will have a field that gives a count of how many features intersect the overlapping feature.  Right click on your polygon layer, then got to Joins and Relates.  Choose Join, the Join by spatial location on the drop down on the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

If this is something you need to enforce and prevent from happening again, you may consider adding a [Must Be Inside](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Geodatabase_topology_rules_and_topology_error_fixes/001t000000sp000000/) topology rule to the feature class. If this is a one-time fix, that may be a little heavy-handed.